# Is it safe to use ElasticSearch 5 alpha in production?

Tags: elasticsearch

We've been using ElasticSearch 2.x in production and we're having problems with fault tolerance as almost every time we shut it down we need to recover it and in some cases we lost some data. We experimented a little with version 5 and it seems to handle crashes better, but the "alpha" label makes it a little scary.

Does anyone have experience running ElasticSearch 5 in production? Are there any specific problems we should expect?

Comment: You can use last stable version. if not recommended from the client, I should say that.

Answer (score 5):

From the official [blog announcement](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-stack-release-5-0-0-alpha-1) published on April 5th, 2016:

> It is an alpha release so don’t put it into production

More generally, you should never use [alpha and beta versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Stages_of_development) into production, it is very risky.

Comment: @Gaffar, do you need any more info regarding this issue?